# boxplot doesn't show all the parameter in R

Tags: r, plot, anova

I write this code to execute an ANOVA for a simple dataframe and I want to draw a boxplot out of it

```
DF <- read.table('chromium.txt',header=TRUE)
Chromium.aov <- aov(Concentration ~ Lab,data=DF)
print(summary(Chromium.aov))

with(DF,boxplot(Concentration,Lab))
```

here is the text file

```
Lab Concentration
1 26.1
1 21.5
1 22.0
1 22.6
1 24.9
1 22.6
1 23.8
1 23.2
2 18.3
2 19.7
2 18.0
2 17.4
2 22.6
2 11.6
2 11.0
2 15.7
3 19.1
3 13.9
3 15.7
3 18.6
3 19.1
3 16.8
3 25.5
3 19.7
4 30.7
```

However, R only show 2 box plots for lab 1 and 2, not 3 and 4, how can I fix this?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `with(DF,boxplot(Concentration,Lab))`, you are providing two sets of values to be plotted - `Concentration` and `lab`. You want to `split` the `Concentration` based on the unique values `Lab` and then create the `boxplot`.

```
boxplot(split(DF$Concentration, DF$Lab))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
boxplot(DF$Concentration ~ DF$Lab)
```

The syntax you used is making one box with all the values of 'Concentration', and another with the values of 'Lab'